# Django testing mirror database not receiving data

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to set up some testing on my Django application. I use a database mirror for some reads done throughout my application. When I try and test these parts, by creating mock data in the database and then attempting to read it, it appears as though the data is not in the mirror database, despite being configured as a `TEST_MIRROR`.

The database config for testing looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'maindb',
    'HOST': 'localhost'
  },
  'mirror1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'maindb',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'TEST_MIRROR': 'default'
  }
}
```

And then in my test I do something like this (Foo is a model)

```
Foo.objects.create(name='bar')
self.assertTrue(Foo.objects.filter(name='bar').exists()) # passes
self.assertTrue(Foo.objects.using('mirror1').filter(name='bar').exists()) # fails
```

This is confusing to me, as I thought the point of the `TEST_MIRROR` was to make calls to the mirror pass straight through to the default?

Answer (score 5):

> If your setup contains multiple databases, and you have a test that
> requires every database, you can use the **multi_db** attribute on the
> test suite to request a full flush.

For example:

```
class TestMyViews(TestCase):
    multi_db = True        # for Django < 3.1 (deprecated since 2.2)
    databases = '__all__'  # for Django >= 2.2
    # databases = {'default', 'other'}  # or explicit databases


    def testIndexPageView(self):
        call_some_test_code()
```

That documentation ([multi-database support testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#multi-database-support)) is not exact, because the condition multi_db (indirectly in _databases_names) is not used only for flush (tearDown) in Django source, but also for '_fixture_setup'. (Django-1.5.1/django/test/testcases.py:834) Therefore it seems to be a basic condition independent on master/slave settings.

Comment: Afraid I don't think that's the answer in this case. We have something like a master/slave relationship in production (on Heroku with a "follower" db), but when doing local dev we just point the db config for both to a single db. When the test is constructing the environment, it goes to create a `_test` copy of each existing database, but since it sees two in the config, it tries to create the same one twice. This is what `TEST_MIRROR` does fix, as it knows not to create the db for the mirror, but it seems not to inform the ORM to pass through queries from the mirror db to the master.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might lie [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-databases):

> When the test environment is configured, a test version of slave will
>   **not be created**. Instead the connection to slave will be redirected to
>   point at default

Since the slave doesn't really exist in the testing, it kinda makes sense that trying to call it directly fails

Comment: I read "Instead the connection to slave will be redirected to point at default" as anything pointed at the slave will pass through to the master, so it seems like it _should_ work. Perhaps it's just a case that I'm reading it wrong (and IMO it could be written more clearly in the docs...)

Comment: I'm not an official source, and I get your point, but my understanding is that this only happens in testing environment

Answer (score 0):

according to the latest [Django 4.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/)

1. [Database Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#mirror) for tests should be defined as

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {...},
    "replica": {..., "TEST": {MIRROR": "default"}}
}
```

2. To check it in tests it you need to use [TransactionTestCase only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#topics-testing-primaryreplica) and  databases = '**all**'

> The alias of the database that this database should mirror during testing. It depends on transactions and therefore must be used within TransactionTestCase instead of TestCase.